# spring demo example

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Dear all, I'm new to spring mvc framework. Plaese share small examples to start with:-

- Displaying data in a page
- Submiting data
- login

Answer (score 3):

The spring petclinic app:

> svn co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk spring-petclinic

The project is created using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), so use Eclipse to import it as well.

Comment: +1 Note that you'll need m2eclipse with Eclipse or... use [SpringSource Tools Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts) which bundles everything required.

Answer (score 0):

How about this [SpringAcegiTutorial-1_1-html.html](http://tfo-eservices.eu/wb_tutorials/media/SpringAcegiTutorial/HTML/SpringAcegiTutorial-1_1-html.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are some good examples in the official docs:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Spring has a document called "Spring MVC step by step" that is a bit dated (uses 2.5 instead of 3.0) but is still full of valuable information:

http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/